# Error:Gradle: ...while parsing ddf/minim/AudioBuffer.class

Tags: android, gradle, minim

I'm using Android 2.2 and I can't compile into app because of an error

```
-Error:Gradle: unsupported class file version 52.0
-Error:Gradle: ...while parsing ddf/minim/AudioBuffer.class
```

It is made on processing.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "processing.test.flappyspace"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/jl1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsminim.jar')
    compile files('libs/minim.jar')
    compile files('libs/mp3spi1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/processing-core.jar')
    compile files('libs/tritonus_aos.jar')
    compile files('libs/tritonus_share.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Minim is not fully supported on Android. The problem might be you're using JDK 7 and Minim is using JDK 8 (just a guess). Although you can [enable JDK 8 on Android](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html?hl=en), not all Java 8 features are supported yet.

I recommend you using [Minim-Android](https://github.com/DASAR/Minim-Android) instead and see if it has all the features you need in your project.